# Using sed command to delete lines in file in Debian Linux

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to ask you if you know how to delete lines in single file using sed command on Linux.

For example I have got file:

```
       something
       something-
       somethingelse
```

And I want create sed command to delete all lines where line contains "something", but also I dont want delete line where is something-. Where is specific char like "-". Thank you for advice.

I tried to make something like sed -i "/something/d".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e '/something[^-]/d' -e '/something$/d' -i "$file"
```

even shorter, proposed by Philippos:

```
sed -i '/something\([^-].*\)*$/d' "$file"
```

Comment: Note that this would _delete_ a line saying `something something-`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is more important to *keep* lines that contain `something-` than it is to *delete* lines that contain `something`:

```bsh
sed '/something/ { /something-/!d; }' file
```

This finds all lines containing the string `something`, and deletes all of those lines unless they also contain `something-`.

Testing:

```
$ cat file
something something blah blah
something something- blah blah
somethingelse
something
something-
```

```
$ sed '/something/ { /something-/!d; }' file
something something- blah blah
something-
```

Comment: Or, almost equivalently (but a few characters shorter, and with no negation), `sed '/something-/n; /something/d;'`